# How to create order notification with array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a notification for the purchase of a car, for data I use the array and I want to display all the data but only one by one appears.

but when I enter data and want to call, it says undefined and the active notification doesn't alternate, only one active item remains.

question: how to make active notification alternately but only one item appears.

```js
    const dataOrder = {
        "data":[
            {user:"riyan",
                image: "",// URL Foto user
                merek: "BMW",// Nama merek
                urlmobil: "#",// URL merek
            },
            {user: "sandi",
                image: "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-QlJpOYV6yF4/XNEPty8zjJI/AAAAAAAAF6k/7RaA8suy7AsVhOYwcP6WLMf2qc54GUXWwCEwYBhgL/h60/ava.png",
            merek: "FORD",// Nama merek
                urlmobil: "#",// URL merek
            },
            {user: "yayang",
                image: "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-QlJpOYV6yF4/XNEPty8zjJI/AAAAAAAAF6k/7RaA8suy7AsVhOYwcP6WLMf2qc54GUXWwCEwYBhgL/h60/ava.png",// URL Foto user
            merek: "AVANZA",// Nama merek
                urlmobil: "#",// URL merek
            },
            {user: "adit",
                image: "",// URL Foto user
                merek: "MUSTANG",// Nama merek
                urlmobil: "#",// URL merek
            },
        ]
    };
    window.addEventListener('load', () =>{
        dataOrder.data.forEach(function (a,b){
            var c = "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-QlJpOYV6yF4/XNEPty8zjJI/AAAAAAAAF6k/7RaA8suy7AsVhOYwcP6WLMf2qc54GUXWwCEwYBhgL/h60/ava.png";
            if (b.image != "") {
                c = b.image
            }
            document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML += '<div class="item"><span class="image" style="background-image:url('+b.image+');"></span><h5><a class="close" href="javascript:void(0);">Close</a></h5><span class="info"><b>'+b.user+'</b> url mobil <a href="'+b.urlmobil+'" target="_blank">'+b.merek+"</a></span></div>";
        })
        
        document.querySelectorAll('.test > .item:not(:first-child)').forEach(function(e){
            e.classList.remove('active')
        })
        setInterval(function(){
            var otif = document.querySelectorAll('.test > .item:first-child');
            otif.forEach(function(e) {
                e.classList.remove('active');
            });
            setTimeout( () =>{
                otif.forEach(function(e) {
                e.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
                })
            },4000)
        },10000);
    })
    document.querySelectorAll('.test .close').forEach(e => {
        e.addEventListener('click', function () {
            e.parentNode('.item').classList.add('hidden')
        }) 
    })
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
```

Comment: There is no JSON in this question; just an object with a property that contains an array of objects. JSON is a text format.

Comment: *'It says undefined"* ...what does? Always post specific error messages and where they occur. They are very meaningful

Comment: just it like same json and i dont now is array object

Comment: undefined when the code is run, I can't retrieve data from the array and also for the active class it doesn't want to alternate with another div. The active class should only be in the first div and then the div alternates with the lower one along with the active class. but I did not succeed, only the active class appears in Element 2.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `forEach(a, b)` wrong.  `b` stands for index and `a` stands for the ojbect on each iteration.  The correct way would be like this:

```js
const dataOrder = {
        "data":[
            {user:"riyan",
                image: "",// URL Foto user
                merek: "BMW",// Nama merek
                urlmobil: "#",// URL merek
            },
            {user: "sandi",
                image: "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-QlJpOYV6yF4/XNEPty8zjJI/AAAAAAAAF6k/7RaA8suy7AsVhOYwcP6WLMf2qc54GUXWwCEwYBhgL/h60/ava.png",
            merek: "FORD",// Nama merek
                urlmobil: "#",// URL merek
            },
            {user: "yayang",
                image: "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-QlJpOYV6yF4/XNEPty8zjJI/AAAAAAAAF6k/7RaA8suy7AsVhOYwcP6WLMf2qc54GUXWwCEwYBhgL/h60/ava.png",// URL Foto user
            merek: "AVANZA",// Nama merek
                urlmobil: "#",// URL merek
            },
            {user: "adit",
                image: "",// URL Foto user
                merek: "MUSTANG",// Nama merek
                urlmobil: "#",// URL merek
            },
        ]
    };
    window.addEventListener('load', () =>{
        dataOrder.data.forEach(function (a,b){
            var c = "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-QlJpOYV6yF4/XNEPty8zjJI/AAAAAAAAF6k/7RaA8suy7AsVhOYwcP6WLMf2qc54GUXWwCEwYBhgL/h60/ava.png";
            if (a.image != "") {
                c = a.image
            }
            document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML += '<div class="item"><span class="image" style="background-image:url('+a.image+');"></span><h5><a class="close" href="javascript:void(0);">Close</a></h5><span class="info"><b>'+a.user+'</b> url mobil <a href="'+a.urlmobil+'" target="_blank">'+a.merek+"</a></span></div>";
        })
        
        document.querySelectorAll('.test > .item:not(:first-child)').forEach(function(e){
            e.classList.remove('active')
        })
        setInterval(function(){
            var otif = document.querySelectorAll('.test > .item:first-child');
            otif.forEach(function(e) {
                e.classList.remove('active');
            });
            setTimeout( () =>{
                otif.forEach(function(e) {
                e.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
                })
            },4000)
        },10000);
    })
    document.querySelectorAll('.test .close').forEach(e => {
        e.addEventListener('click', function () {
            e.parentNode('.item').classList.add('hidden')
        }) 
    })
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
```

Comment: successful for data display, only for active class cannot run according to procedure. The active class should only appear in the first div item element and alternate with the others

Answer (score 1):

Inside your [`foreach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop you can get the current element being processed like this:

```
dataOrder.data.forEach(function(item, index) {
     // item.image
     // item.merek
     // ...
});
```

**Edit:** The `active` class will now be applied to the elements in a cyclic manner. Support was also added for clicking on the `close` anchor tag. The elements will now disappear when clicked on `close` and the loop will skip them when applying class `active`. If all elements have been closed (hidden) the interval will be canceled. The interval times have also been altered so we can quickly see the results here.

See below:

```js
const dataOrder = {
    "data":[
        {
            user:"riyan",
            image: "",// URL Foto user
            merek: "BMW",// Nama merek
            urlmobil: "#",// URL merek
        },
        {
            user: "sandi",
            image: "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-QlJpOYV6yF4/XNEPty8zjJI/AAAAAAAAF6k/7RaA8suy7AsVhOYwcP6WLMf2qc54GUXWwCEwYBhgL/h60/ava.png",
            merek: "FORD",// Nama merek
            urlmobil: "#",// URL merek
        },
        {
            user: "yayang",
            image: "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-QlJpOYV6yF4/XNEPty8zjJI/AAAAAAAAF6k/7RaA8suy7AsVhOYwcP6WLMf2qc54GUXWwCEwYBhgL/h60/ava.png",// URL Foto user
            merek: "AVANZA",// Nama merek
            urlmobil: "#",// URL merek
        },
        {
            user: "adit",
            image: "",// URL Foto user
            merek: "MUSTANG",// Nama merek
            urlmobil: "#",// URL merek
        }
    ]
};

window.addEventListener('load', () =>{
    dataOrder.data.forEach(function(item) {
        var img = "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-QlJpOYV6yF4/XNEPty8zjJI/AAAAAAAAF6k/7RaA8suy7AsVhOYwcP6WLMf2qc54GUXWwCEwYBhgL/h60/ava.png";
        if (item.image != "") {
            img = item.image;
        }

        document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML += '<div class="item"><span class="image" style="background-image:url('+ img +');"></span><h5><a class="close" href="javascript:void(0);">Close</a></h5><span class="info"><b>'+ item.user +'</b> url mobil <a href="'+ item.urlmobil +'" target="_blank">'+ item.merek +"</a></span></div>";
    });

    function removeActive() {
        let idx;
        
        allItems.forEach(function(item, index) {
            if(item.classList.contains('active')) {
                item.classList.remove('active');
                idx = index + 1;                     
            }
        });
        
        return idx;   // return index of next element to be active
    }

    function addActive(idx) {
        for(let i=idx; i < allItems.length; i++) {           // start from next index to be active
            if(!allItems[i].classList.contains('hidden')) {  // if item doesn't conatin class hidden
                allItems[i].classList.add('active');         // then make active
                return;                                      // return from function
            } else {
                idx = i + 1;                                 // otherwise increase index
            }
        }

        // if function got to this point it didn't find non-hidden elements to activate
        // the below instruction gets all non hidden elements
        let nonHiddenItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('div.test > div.item:not(.hidden)')];
        if(nonHiddenItems.length == 0) {               // if there are no non-hidden elements
            clearInterval(interval);                   // then stop the interval
        } else {
            nonHiddenItems[0].classList.add('active'); // otherwise set the first non-hidden to be active
        }
    }

    // get all divs with class item whos parent is a div with class test
    var allItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('div.test > div.item')];
    allItems[0].classList.add('active');      // set first element to be active for initial start

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        let idx = removeActive();             // returns index of next element to activate
        setTimeout( () => {
            addActive(idx);                   // searches for next non-hidden element to activate
        }, 1000)
    }, 2000);

    // you need to put the below code inside `window.addEventListener('load',...` function since 
    // the HTML elements you're targeting exist only after the window load event gets triggered
    document.querySelectorAll('.test a.close').forEach(e => {
        e.addEventListener('click', function () {
            this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('hidden');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
```

Comment: successful for data display, only for active class cannot run according to procedure. The active class should only appear in the first div item element and alternate with the others.

Comment: @CodingT if an answer on this page solved your problem please consider marking at as accepted. Thanks!